# Create dictionary of dictionaries Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary of dictionaries as the title reads and looking at the simplest way to do so.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
+----------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| Exchange | currency_code | interest rate                 |
+----------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| TOCN     | JPY           |                         0.525 |
| SGX      | SGD           |                         2.575 |
| SGX      | JPY           |                         0.725 |
| SGX      | USD           |                         2.605 |
| SGX      | CNH           |                         5.005 |
| SGX      | CNY           |                           0.0 |
| OSE      | JPY           |                         0.615 |
| NLFX     | USD           |                         3.305 |
| KIS      | KRW           |                           0.0 |
| HKEX     | USD           |                         3.395 |
| HKEX     | HKD           |                         3.265 |
| HKEX     | CNH           |                         4.895 |
| GOODM    | KRW           |                           0.0 |
| CME      | JPY           |                         0.525 |
| CME      | USD           |                         3.305 |
| CME      | CNH           |                         4.805 |
| Combined | JPY           |                         0.615 |
| Combined | USD           |                         3.305 |
| Combined | HKD           |                         4.155 |
| Combined | GBP           |                         1.545 |
| Combined | TWD           |                           0.0 |
| Combined | EUR           |                         0.375 |
+----------+---------------+-------------------------------+
```

I would like to create a dictionary(all the exchanges) of 
dictionaries(currencies and interest rates).

What I tried:

```
interestrate_dict = dict(zip(interestrate1['currency_code'],interestrate1['interest rate']))
```

But how do i loop it to do it for all the exchanges?

Should I filter the dataframe and create each dictionary or is there a simpler way to do it?

Expected Output:

SGX :

```
| SGD           |                         2.575 |
| JPY           |                         0.725 |
| USD           |                         2.605 |
| CNH           |                         5.005 |
| CNY           |                           0.0 |
```

TOCN:

```
| JPY           |                         0.525 |
```

HKEX:

```
| USD           |                         3.395 |
| HKD           |                         3.265 |
| CNH           |                         4.895 |
```

Comment: can you specify more information and your expected answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something along the lines of:

```
df.groupby("Exchange").apply( lambda x: dict(zip(x["interest rate"],x["currency_code "])) )
```

I'm not sure why you would want a nested dict structure, I'd rather recommend using the index functions of pandas directly

if you set the index:

```
A = df.set_index(["Exchange","interest rate"])
```

then you can do the look-ups like in a dictionary

```
A.loc[(myExchange,myInterestare)]
```